s3.get_presigned_url , different behavior Python SDK vs AWS CLI
This seems like a silly question but I can't understand why the s3 presigned URL I generate through the AWS CLI correctly contains the region: <bucket-name>.s3.<region-name>.amazonaws.com, whereas the one created programmatically using boto3 is of the form: <bucket-name>.s3.amazonaws.com, thus giving me this error when I try to open the URL:
<Code>IllegalLocationConstraintException</Code>
<Message>The <region-name> location constraint is incompatible for the region specific endpoint this request was sent to.</Message>

I am creating the s3 client object in this way:
s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=..., aws_secret_access_key=..., region_name=region_name)

@edit
This is the code I'm using for my lambda (local debug)
import json
import boto3
from botocore.config import Config

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3', aws_access_key_id=<access-key>, aws_secret_access_key=<secret-key>, 
                      config=Config(signature_version='s3v4'), region_name=<region>)

    presigned_url = s3.generate_presigned_url(
        'get_object',
        Params={'Bucket': <bucket-name>, 'Key': <object-name>},
        ExpiresIn=3600  # Expiration time in seconds (1 hour)
    )
    
    return {"body":json.dumps({"url":presigned_url}),
            "isBase64Encoded":False}


Try creating client with extra parameter: config=Config(signature_version='s3v4').

Tried adding the config, but didn't change the issue

Presumably you supplied the correct region_name parameter value when creating the client, and it's actually the region in which the S3 bucket exists.

@jarmod Thanks for answering, ,but I double checked and the region is the same. Which is the issue?

There's no place to pass region when calling generate_presigned_url (not even in the params that are passed on to get_object) so the only place afaik that it's relevant is when creating the client object. You should probably add a minimal version of your code that reproduces the error so we are sure we know what you are actually running.

added the relevant code
